# What is the different between df.loc[anything].index and iloc?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm confused because when I dropped a row, but I can continue consulting the row with df.iloc[  ] after I dropped it, but the script shows the information is the next row.

I understood ilow = row index but not, can you explain to me what is the mistake?

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=6, size=(10,4)),columns ={'a','b','c','d'})
```

df

```
a   b   c   d
```

1. 0   3   0   4
2. 0   0   1   1
3. 0   1   1   2
4. 1   1   5   5
5. 4   2   3   5
6. 4   2   0   2
7. 2   1   1   4
8. 4   3   2   4
9. 5   2   5   5
10. 2   5   0   0

    df.loc[df['c']==5].index

Int64Index([3, 8], dtype='int64')

```
df.iloc[3]
```

a    1
b    1
c    5
d    5
Name: 3, dtype: int64

```
df = df.drop(df.loc[df['c']==5].index, axis = 0)
```

df

```
a   b   c   d
```

1. 0   3   0   4
2. 0   0   1   1
3. 0   1   1   2
4. 4   2   3   5
5. 4   2   0   2
6. 2   1   1   4
7. 4   3   2   4
8. 2   5   0   0

   df.iloc[3]

a    4
b    2
c    3
d    5
Name: 4, dtype: int64

In this case, I expected an exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.loc returns data based on labels (index, columns names). iloc returns data based purely on position (index position, column position) starting from 0.

Your first line of code is creating a slice of the dataframe based on the condition. df.index returned the index of the slice.

```
df.loc[df['c']==5].index
Int64Index([3, 8], dtype='int64')
```

The second line, since you passed only one value, pandas assumed it to be index and returns all the elements at the specified index.

```
df.iloc[3]

a    1
b    1
c    5
d    5
```

Once you dropped the index number 3, df.iloc[3] will once again return 4th row as the 4th position still exists. On the other hand, using loc will throw keyerror as the dataframe does not have index number 3 in the data anymore.

```
df.loc[3]
KeyError: 'the label [3] is not in the [index]'
```